# Sublime Text 3 CSS Modules - correct syntax for 'composes' but semicolon is highlighted

Tags: sublimetext3, css-modules

I am using the CSS Modules `composes:` selector in ST3 but I can't figure out how to remove the pink highlighting from the semicolon. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: are you using a third party CSS syntax definition / package?

Comment: Yes, currently using these - emmet, babel, sublimeCodeIntel, TypeScript, Side Bar